# Convert ImageView in bytes android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ImageView,to which I am assigning a qr code which I have generated using zxing library.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qrcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />
```

This is my imageview and I want to convert this ImageView in bytes first and then to bytearray. HOw can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

**How to convert View into Bitmap**

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrcode);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

**Convert Bitmap into ByteArray**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrcode);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
System.out.println("byte array:"+image);

String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the image->`image=(Imageview)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);`

convert into byte array

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println("byte array:"+image);
        Log.d("array",image)
        String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
        Log.d("array_Str",image_str)
        System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
```